# Why does using @import url(./assets/Roboto/roboto-font.css); not work?

Tags: css, fonts

My directory structure is

```
-app
-main.css
  -assets
     -Roboto
        -roboto-font.css
        -Roboto font files...
```

But when I use 
`@import url("./assets/Roboto/roboto-font.css");`
in my `main.css` file but the font doesn't apply to any elements. This is the contents of `roboto-font.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url(./Roboto-Thin.ttf) format('tff');
}
```

Comment: Which folder is your `main.css` in?

Comment: Strong recommendation to not use `ttf`, it's was never meant for webfont use. Use `woff2`/`woff` and [don't have anything else in there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270092/why-does-using-import-url-assets-roboto-roboto-font-css-not-work).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Should I rename the files to end in woff2/woff? Or just replace format with woff2/woff?

Comment: You should make sure you _have_ the `.woff2` and `.woff` files in your dir, and then point to those in your font-face src, following the rules for how to point to a file (using `url()`) and how to indicate the format (using `format()`). And on a sidenote, `format("ttf")` doesn't exist, so it's worth giving https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face a read-through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the font directly from google by adding this

```css
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

And using it with this `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`
You can find more details here https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto

Answer (score 1):

When you use a path starting with a `./` this means the path should start from the current directory. If your main.css file is in the app folder, it will import the roboto-font.css file correctly.

However, the roboto-font.css file is trying to import the font file from the path `./assets/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf` while roboto-font.css itself is already inside `assets/Roboto`. You should remove the `assets/Roboto` from this `url()` property as all font files are already in the same directory as this stylesheet. Try using `url(./Roboto-Thin.ttf)`.

Also try to use appropriate web font formats, or just import from Google as suggested by @Radu.